# ActionbarActivity class or FragmentActivity class

Tags: android

I want to create an activity that uses action bar ui pattern and fragments. Which base class my activity should extend, ActionbarActivity or FragmentActivity?

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is a sub class of `FragmentActivity`...

Comment: ^^ but why don't you just try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

ActionBarActivity is the right answer

Comment: Yes, that's all you need

Answer (score 0):

As @Pontus said, it depends on the way your requirements are:

1. If you are aiming API 11+ then you should go for FragmentActivity.
2. If you want to have your app compatible to older devices version 2.1+ then you will need the support library, ActionBarActivity.
3. In addition to ActionBarActivity, you have a very customized and easy to use library by Jake, ActionBar Sherlock available and its easy to implement as well. So if you wanna customize the actionbar and want it to be flexible you can even go for this.

Try and choose the best suit o your shoes. Happy Coding :)